# WebView does not resize correctly after being loaded

Tags: android, android-webview, zooming

I'm having trouble resizing my `WebView` after loading JQuery [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) graph API.

So, here's my code:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        // view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        webview.setInitialScale(100);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    }
});

webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.addJavascriptInterface(this, "webConnector");

webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/graph_test_json.html");
```

Sometimes, the `WebView` is correctly displayed. The graph is fully zoommed out, so we can see it all.

Sometimes, the `WebView` is "too much zoomed" (a double tap on the `WebView` makes it zoom out correctly and the graph fits the screen).

How comes the `WebView` cannot be always correctly zoomed out? Is there a trick to force the `WebView` zooming out?

- I tried to reload the page but it does not work.
- I tried to apply those three lines:

  ```
  webview.setInitialScale(100);
  webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
  webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
  ```

after `onResume()` of the activity and it doesn't work either.

Can we programmatically zoom out a `WebView`?